# Database Batch Update

Tags: sql, database, batch-processing, mybatis, batch-updates

What is difference between these three solutions in terms of batch-update definition and performance:

1)

```
Insert into table1 values ('A','A1'),('B','B1'),('C','C1'), ....
```

2)

```
Transaction.begin();

insert into table1 values('A','A1'); insert into table1
values('B','B1'); insert into table1 values('C','C1'); ... ... ...

Transaction.commit();
```

3)

```
PreparedStatement.addBatch(...);
PreparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

OR Set `Batch=true` in MyBatis  configuration

Comment: The first one involves less typing but will not work with every database engine.

Comment: I mean all of them are Batch updating?

Comment: @DanBracuk: the first version will not work with Oracle and older SQL Server versions.

Comment: It won't work with redbrick either.  That's why I said that it would not work with every database engine.

Comment: Is the preparedStatement a reference to the Java library?

Comment: yes, it is a java referencing

Comment: Depends on the database server. 1 and 2 are acting on the server but in most databases there will be an implied transaction whether you start one or not. If this isn't the case in 1 you will have to commit to see the data in the db. I'd assume in many cases 1 and 2 will be equivalent. With 3 you'll have the overhead of jdbc connection handling which may be different to the overhead of the native connection. You would need to benchmark this for your setup and see what happens

Comment: In almost all cases #2 will be slower than the other two options. Whether #1 or #3 is faster depends on the DBMS and the JDBC driver. For Oracle #3 will be faster (because it doesn't support #1 and batching is extremely well optimized in the driver) and for Postgres #1 will be faster (because the driver does not really do batching)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your database takes syntax 1 as valid (MS-SQL 2008 for example) and assuming #1 and #2 are both in native database's SQL implementation...

Then for performance part of your question...

#1 is the fastest because it will be parsed/prepared once and executed once as a single atomic transaction.

#2 will be next in performance. There are two statements (txn begin) and (txn end) as well as one statement each for each insert.

#2a (something I suggest) works faster. It is when, depending on your server's supported syntax, you "prepare" a parametrized SQL and repeatedly call the prepared statement (execute) with each of your values as parameters. This way the actual statement is parsed only once. E.g.

```
  Transaction.begin();  
  Stmt.Prepare("insert into table1 values(:Var1, :Var2)");  
  Stmt.Execute('A','A1');  
  Stmt.Execute('B','B1');  
  Stmt.Execute('C','C1');  
  Transaction.commit();
```

#3 is an based on an ORM framework so it will have it's own overhead and will be slower than for #1 and #2a. But could be faster than #2 depending on how it's implemented. In rare cases #3 could be even faster than both #1 and #2a, ***"IF"*** the ORM framework internally is intelligent enough to change such repeated inserts into database specific bulk load calls.

For batch-update definition part of your question...

That's also basically a multi-part decision....
 #A a subjective choice of taste.
 #B can it do the job at hand..

I personally like the #2a because it is pretty much as fast as #1 but more readable and also able to take on a much larger dataset, or can be put in a loop, reading values from a stream/file etc. and inserting them, whereas #1 is sometimes limited by maximum SQL statement size of a particular DBMS implementation.
 #3 and other variations really depend on the ORM framework you are using so it's hard to get any more specific.

This is a broad question, so I've kept the answer broad also. If anything specific is not clear, comment please and I'll be happy to expand.